# how to select even rows and exclude last column

Tags: html, css

i want to add some style to my html table but can't make a certain selection in css, i want to select every even row except every last column of each one!
i already know how to select every even row usin: ":nth-child(even)" but i can't make it exclude the last column!

```
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>age</td>
                    <td>country</td>
                    <td id="rmv"><button>remove</button></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: `:nth-child(even):not(:last-child)` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif no this made it exclude the whole last row! i need to exclude only last column fro m each even row

Comment: selecting *rows* and excluding *columns*? can you be more clear, doesn't make sense to me

Comment: `tr:last-child:{}` now just override within.

Comment: @TemaniAfif every row contains cells that belongs to columns i mean !
so for example i need to select even rows and exclude from each row  the last cell that belongs last column!

Comment: you add a space then `:nth-child(even) :not(:last-child)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow that actually worked ! thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `tr` elements that are even with `tr:nth-child(even)` followed by excluding the last `td` `td:not(:last-child)`, the selector becomes `tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:last-child)`

```css
tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:last-child) {
  background-color: #f00;
}


/** only for demo purposes **/

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
    <td>country</td>
    <td id="rmv"><button>remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
    <td>country</td>
    <td id="rmv"><button>remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
    <td>country</td>
    <td id="rmv"><button>remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
    <td>country</td>
    <td id="rmv"><button>remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```